# How to configure connected service in an Azure Function after using wsdl to create via WCF Web Service Reference

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-functions, app-config, soap-client

I am able to implement a connected service in a console app via the service reference option in VS using a wsdl.  The following configuration changes are required in the app.config for the service to work:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="......">
          <security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" includeTimestamp="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
            <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:10:00" detectReplays="false" />
            <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:10:00" detectReplays="false" />
            <secureConversationBootstrap>
              <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" />
              <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
            </secureConversationBootstrap>
            <issuedTokenParameters useStrTransform="true"></issuedTokenParameters>
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" requireClientCertificate="true">
          </httpsTransport>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="...." binding="...." behaviorConfiguration="....." bindingConfiguration="....." contract="...." name="...." />
    </client>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="....">
        <clientCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate>
            <defaultCertificate storeLocation="..." storeName="..." findValue="...." x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I using the same wsdl to setup a connected service in an Azure Function via WCF Web Service Reference the result does not an app.config.  How do I implement the app.config above in the Azure Function connected service?

Comment: When you add a service reference, the configuration file is automatically generated. You can directly use the proxy class to call the wcf service after adding the service reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) tool to generate proxy classes and config files and add them to your project to implement calls.